# Moving multiple objects at once

Tags: transforms, normals, axis

I'm trying to move a set of objects along say x-axis, I select them all and try to shift them, but all of them are aligned to the different axis,  so they move along different axes.
[image: As you can see the green lines, they all move along those lines.]
How do I quickly fix this.
P.S. I'm an absolute beginner

Comment: I think you need to change the transform orientation from local to global. By default, it’s in the header of the 3-D view port.

Comment: yes, i did that but that doesn't help

Comment: Do you have it set for individual origins for the transform or median point?

Comment: for individual origins

Comment: Change it to median point.